# Send keys to background window/application (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, keyboard, filesystems

I'm currently working on a Selenium program that requires I open up a system file-selector dialog. Unfortunately it's impossible to circumvent this by just sending keys to a webpage attribute, as I have to select a button with no file-acceptance, which automatically opens up the file-selector dialog.

I believe the only solution is to send keys through the system itself to the file selector. Unfortunately, the method I'm currently using (below) requires that the window be active for it to receive the keys.

I used the pynput library in order to send the keys on my first iteration. The pynput documentation for keyboards can be found here:
https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import os, time

file = "723583.jpg" #this is a local directory file
keyboard = Controller()
keyboard.type(os.path.abspath(file))
time.sleep(5) #Please ignore the bad style of using these sleeps
keyboard.press(Key.enter) #They're just for testing
time.sleep(3)
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
time.sleep(3)
```

On other Stackoverflow questions, I've found solutions for Windows computers (e.g. using win32), though I haven't been able to find anything for MacOS, which I'm currently using, or an equivalent multi-platform solution. Does anybody know how I might be able to send keys to a background application as such?

Comment: Sorry to say, according to much of my research I don't think pynput can choose which window it sends keys too. If it did then it would be documented.

Comment: Yes, this is true. Unfortunately after searching for hours and not finding a solution, I don't believe there is a presently-existing solution to this